# When I give a 'function' type to onclick, it show me the exception InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, ngui

Now I'm using UIEventListener to add a clicker.When I write it in one file, it works all right.like this:
`UIEventListener.Get(popButton).onClick = showPop;`

But when I wrote it to two seprate files it gives me error.first file:

```
public class Adapter{
    var grid:GameObject;

    function addItems(data:List.<PrintItem>, prefab:GameObject, func:Function){
        for(var i:int=0;i<data.Count;i++){
            var gameObject:GameObject = NGUITools.AddChild(grid, prefab);
            UIEventListener.Get(gameObject).onClick = func;
        }
    }
}
```

second file:

```
//I use the funtion like this
adapter.addItems(list, GO[0], hidePop);
//the hidePop is like this
var hidePop:Function = function(){
    switchPopMenu(false);
};
```

when I run the unity give me the error

```
InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
Adapter.addItems (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 data,   
UnityEngine.GameObject prefab, ICallable func) (at
Assets/Scripts/yhj/Tools/Adapter.js:12)
```

Comment: What is in Adapter.js on line 12? `UIEventListener.Get(gameObject).onClick = func;`?

Answer (score 0):

try using `EventDelegate.Add(obj.onClick, func);`. Direct assignment may cause certain issues.